# how to replace ... between a word where one part is numeric the other is'int?

Tags: php, string, replace

how can i put a space between a word where one part is numeric the other is'int? like so:

```
$string = "this is a 2000px height photo";
$string = preg_replace('???',' //1',$string);
echo $string; //this is a 2000 px height photo
```

can someone help me? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace('/(\d+)([[:alpha:]]+)/', '$1 $2', $string);
```

- `\d+` matches any digit
- `[[:alpha:]]+` matches any letter (`\w+` is wrong because matches letters *and digits*: the `preg_replace()` call splits numbers - e.g. '100' becomes '10 0')

Comment: this is good..but somehow this splits the sinlge numeric too (exapmple: "10 images 2000px height photo" youll get this:"1 0 images 2000 px height photo")